# $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an algebra over a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> A ring $R$ is called an algebra over a field $k$ whenever $R$ is a vector space over $k$ and $λ(rs) = (λr)s = r(λs)$ for all $λ ∈ k$, $r$, $s ∈ R$. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an algebra over a field.

Is it correct to say that since $\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be a vector space over any field, it cannot be an algebra?

Edit: Is it possible to prove this without using the above fact? The proof of the above fact involves something I haven't learnt, so I guess I should be able to solve this problem by showing that suppose $\mathbb{Z}$ can be a vector space over a field, and it would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Yes. Though the exercise might want you to show that, too.

Comment: No.  An "algebra" is also defined over a commutative ring and that concept is *very* widely used.  You can say $\mathbf Z$ is not an "algebra over a field" but  it sounds strange to say $\mathbf Z$ is not "an algebra" at all.  It is an algebra over itself. The situation is sort of like if someone learns about groups only for abelian groups and asks if $S_3$ is not a group.  According to a too restrictive definition where the operation is commutative, $S_3$ is "not a group" but according to how the term "group" is used in math generally, $S_3$ is definitely a group.

Comment: @ε-δ Yes, but I was wondering if there is a way to solve the prolem without using this.